# upgrade typescript to 4.2.x, An import path cannot end with '.ts'?

Tags: typescript

when i upgrade typescript from 4.1.5 to 4.3.2, my progrom cannot build.

the error info： An import path cannot end with a '.ts' extension. Consider importing '@/api/common.js' instead.

version 4.1.5 is ok。Is it not allowed to use .ts extention after 4.2.x?

my tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2019",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "strict": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "jest"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "includes": ["../shared/**/**"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```